# Streaming data from multiple api calls using nodejs and socket io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, streaming

I am new to socket.io. I have a backend server implemented on nodejs which makes multiple async calls to rest api and send the response back to the client on angular 4.0. I follow the simple http request methodology. However, the issue is that it takes a while for the server to get collect and parse data from each multiple apis and send it back to the client. Therefore, I wanted to implement streaming which will return data to the client as soon as it gets from anywhere. I wanted to know if this can be done efficiently using web sockets and socket.io or is there another way around to do this. 
I know, we can make async calls from the client but i want to implement the logic on the server rather than the client.
Note: I donot have realtime data

Comment: Yes. You can do it using socket.io. And it good ideas. Alternatively, you can fetch only first rows, and the client will fetch more data when it needs it.

Comment: @Aminadav thank you for the reply. "Alternatively, you can fetch only first rows, and the client will fetch more data when it needs it". how? by using http request streaming?

Comment: @NaufalKhalid Yes like feeds works on social media. Initially only some posts are loaded and the user should load more data by scrolling or clicking on "Show more"

Comment: @MohamedAymenKarmous it is just how you implement on the client then?